# How do I handle files in Google Docs from my previous employer?

Tags: professionalism, new-job

The previous company I worked for shared files with me through google docs. I'm about to start a new job next week and I still have full access to the files.

I would never use these files but it worries me that I still have access to them (2 weeks after I ceased employment there). I left on good terms and I'm very trust worthy but still it makes me feel uneasy having access to them when I'm starting with a competitor.

What would be the correct procedure here?

Comment: download them and save them off some where for future reference, then delete them from you google drive:

Comment: ... were you even supposed to be using Google docs via company policy?

Comment: were you even supposed to have company documents on personal off site storage at all?

Comment: @GregMcNulty - they're not my documents just shared with me for reference.

Comment: @enderland the company isn't ISO accredited so there are no strict rules in place on using Google docs or cloud storage.

Comment: Also, you can 'remove' the file from the 'Shared with me' on your google drive. That does NOT remove your access, but at least gets it out of your view.

Comment: could always just make a single, very noticable, but pointless edit (add a row to the top of a spreadsheet saying "hello world, digital here, make sure to remove me from this access :)") - nothing gets the point across like realizing the actual danger of the situation

Comment: @GregMcNulty: That's a bad idea. Deleting them from your Google Drive will in most cases delete the file for everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Determine who is the proper IT support for this Google docs connection. It might be at the project level, or at the corporate level. Send them a note.

If the sharing of documents using Google docs was blessed by your old boss send a note to them to make him aware of the situation. If the Google docs was not done by corporate IT, you don't want to get them involved.

It is possible that the company has not incorporated turning off access to these types of services into their separation procedures. On your last day you returned your badge, keys, credit card; the company also needs to revoke access to these services.

Comment: Thanks, it was blessed by my old boss (he shared them with me in the first place). I've already mentioned to them that my access needs to be revoked. I'll contact them today.